# Plpgsql - Iterate over a recordset multiple times

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I have a table with series of months with cumulative activity e.g.

`month | activity`

Jan-15 | 20

Feb-15 | 22

I also have a series of thresholds in another table e.g. 50, 100, 200. I need to get the date when the threshold is reached i.e. activity >= threshold.

The way I thought of doing this is to have a pgsql function that reads in the thresholds table, iterates over that cursor and reads in the months table to a cursor, then iterating over those rows working out the month where the threshold is reached. For performance reasons, rather than selecting all rows in the months table each time, I would then go back to the first row in the cursor and re-iterate over with the new value from the thresholds table.

Is this a sensible way to approach the problem? This is what I have so far - I am getting a 
`ERROR: cursor "curs" already in use` error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.function()
  RETURNS SETOF schema.row_type AS
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
rec RECORD;
rectimeline RECORD;
notification_threshold int;
notification_text text;
notification_date date;
output_rec schema.row_type;
curs SCROLL CURSOR FOR select * from schema.another_function_returning_set(); -- this is months table
curs2 CURSOR FOR select * from schema.notifications_table;

BEGIN
OPEN curs;
FOR rec IN curs2 LOOP
notification_threshold := rec.threshold;
LOOP
FETCH curs INTO rectimeline; -- this line seems to be the problem - not sure why cursor is closing
IF notification_threshold >= rectimeline.activity_total THEN
notification_text := rec.housing_notification_text;
notification_date := rectimeline.active_date;
SELECT notification_text, notification_date INTO output_rec.notification_text, output_rec.notification_date;
MOVE FIRST from curs;
RETURN NEXT output_rec;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct on (t.threshold) *
from
    thresholds t
    inner join
    months m on t.threshold < m.activity
order by t.threshold desc, m.month
```

Comment: Doh! I thought something like this could work, but I dismissed it - never underestimate the power of sql! It only worked when I changed it to `months m on t.threshold < m.activity` - assume that is something to do with the join. Also the `order by` clause seems to be very important here. Note to self - understand this query!

Comment: @Stev_k _It only worked when I changed it to `months m on t.threshold < m.activity`_ Sure my mistake. But then you had to change to `order by t.threshold **desc**`, hadn't you?

Comment: funnily enough, no I didn't. I would have thought that that would be necessary as I thought distinct chooses the first unique entry but it seemed to work ok for me without changing the order - not sure why.